# What is the next number in sequence and why?

Tags: number-sequence

What is the next number in sequence and why?

> 7, 8, 5, 5, 3, 4, ...

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C8%2C5%2C5%2C3%2C4&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Probably best to google the question before posting ;-)

Comment: Yea this one was very easy to solve with a quick internet search of the numbers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The next number is:

> 4

Explanation:

> The $n$-th term is the number of letters in the name of the $n-$th month of the English Calendar:
>     January=$7$, February=$8$, March=$5$, April=$5$, May=$3$, June=$4$, July=$4$ etc.

Answer (score 9):

This looks like :

> the number of letters in [English words for months of year](https://oeis.org/A031139).
>   7, 8, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 6, 9, 7, 8, 8

Comment: @Ankoganit beat you by 42 seconds. :P

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes, I shouldn't have spent time adding the link :p

Comment: oh, the things we do for perfectionism :P. I have on multiple occasions answered too slowly because I wanted my post to be 100% complete.

Answer (score 5):

The answer would be "any number you want it to be" since no domain, range, mapping, function, etc" is defined.
I would think it possible to say the numbers represent the age of a person's nieces and nephews in the order of which ones live the farthest to closest away (in miles).